# An example of xVal with ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, xval

This is a two part question.

1. Is it possible to take advantage of [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/)'s automatic client side validation with ASP.NET WebForms?
2. If so, are there any examples available?

I imagine that it would be possible to extend xVal to include ASP.NET Validator controls. These controls would be the WebForms equivalent of <%= Html.ClientSideValidation() %> for MVC.  But before I dive in too deep, I wanted to see if anyone else has tried this. (And yes I did try [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=xval+webforms), but the results weren't very helpful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [xVal CodePlex forum](http://xval.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=60906):

> I think it should be possible to adapt
>   xVal to work with ASP.NET WebForms.
>   However to keep the xVal project
>   focused, I don't want to try adding
>   that support and would rather make the
>   MVC experience as streamlined as
>   possible.
>
> Feel free to have a go yourself
>   though!

-- [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/01/10/xval-a-validation-framework-for-aspnet-mvc/), xVal cooridinator

So when I have some time, I'll see if I can't modify the xVal source to work with WebForms.

**Update**: I've created [xVal.WebForms](http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/), a CodePlex project for this. See my [blog post](http://www.jrummell.com/blog/index.php/tag/xval-webforms/) for details.

Comment: I'm not using WebForms but this post has helped me integrate xVal into my own custom web server. Thanks for the post!